# Create a VueJS frontend for an existing PHP backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I've made an application in PHP, which is also accessible as REST API.
Now I want to create the frontend part in Vue.js.
I've got Visual Studio (not to be confused with VS code) installed and this is my favorite IDE for almost everything. Because I've never created a Vue.js project before, I had to setup things in Visual Studio.
I followed the steps on MDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/quickstart-vuejs-with-nodejs?view=vs-2019
Then I created a VueJs project in Visual Studio, made something simple that shows an image, and run the application. It opens in the webbrowser, and when I'm playing with browser dev tools, I see things that make me think the Vue app relies on NodeJS running on the server. Examples:

- When there's an img element, the src attribute is changed to `/img/myImage.png` while the actual path (in code) to the image is `/assets/myImage.png`
  In other words, the paths are changed to something that doesn't correspond to the file structure of the project. Which means it is not statically served. The only possible way the image could be accessible via that fictional `/img/...` path is that there's some kind of "routing" on the server, which is probably done with NodeJS running on the "server" (which is actually just my PC 'running' the project).
- When I try to visit a random path like `/foo/bar` I expect a default behavior like a 404 response or even the built-in webbrowser page saying the file doesn't exist, but the 'frontpage' (the Vue.js application) is served instead. This again is a clue that something serverside must be happening to get this behavior, and this means serverside logic (NodeJS...) is interwoven through my project.

Of course I had to install NodeJs when setting up the environment for developing VueJs applications. I know I had to do this so I've got the build tools. But I didn't expect some NodeJS is running when I run my project.
I find it hard to explain what I want to achieve.
I want to create a VueJS project that is 100% frontend code and doesn't rely on any serverside code. It should be servable as static html, js, css files. The only thing it has to do, is communicating with my API made in PHP running on that server. The intention was that when the project was finished, I could move all files to my webhost via FTP, and serve it there, without even changing any backend code.

Or maybe the easiest way to explain: I want a create my frontend with Vue, that consists of files that can be statically served. NodeJS's only role should be that it runs on my PC to compile the Vue project, see is as part of development tool. Everything outside of the development process shouldn't be aware of the existence of NodeJS. In theory, when I compile the Vue project, it should consist of files I could open in my webbrowser directly as a file, and it should work.

What should I do to achieve this?
I know the two relations between NodeJS and Vue:

1. The build tools to compile your code to a runnable Vue frontend, are written in JS that must be run on your system by NodeJS, to be able to compile your project and use cli tools.
2. You can choose NodeJS as backend technology. But in my case that's PHP.
   Everywhere it seems that Vue and NodeJS are inherently connected but that's not true.

Maybe it's something simple in my project setup or project type in Visual Studio? My project type is: *Standalone JavaScript Vue project*.

Things I tried:

- Searching the internet for hours.
- Fiddling with Visual Studio.
- Inspecting the app in web browser when "debugging" the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Dev work will often require Node for installing/managing dependencies, and running scripts to build/bundle the app.  The final app bundle that you'll make for production will not use Node.  Node is required to build that bundle, but is not integrated into the final app.  The entire bundle once you build it you'll see is just `.js`, `.html` and `.css` files, capable of being served on an HTTP server.

Comment: How to create that bundle in Visual Studio, to test it?

Comment: Run `npm run build` where package.json is, should be the project root folder.  It will create a `dist` directory with the production files ready for deployment.